# What is the correct way to call a move constructors on the derived class?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

I'm writing a piece of code that inherits from a user provided class (not for polymorphism reasons).
I need to write an explicit move constructor/assignment for it because I store pointers to some internal data of my class.
I don't know how to call move constructor well.

Example:

```
template <typename UserType>
class my_class : UserType  {
  other_data data;
 public:
  my_class(my_class&& x) UserType(/*...*/), data(std::move(x.data)) {}
};
```

Options:

- I can call `move(x)` => but then it's use after move.
- I can do some `static_cast<UserType&&>(x)` - but that's quite unusual.

What's a good solution here?

Comment: I am currently pretty unclear of what you are trying to achieve. Could you please provide some use-case examples?

Comment: @KaenbyouRin - sure.

Sometimes, in containers and things like that you need to store a pointer to an internals of your class (std::string or std::function do that for example).

Sometimes also those things need to store user types that might be small, or provide extensions or smth - which necessitates the use of a 'empty base optimization'.

Here is an example of a flat_multiset_buffered: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/zbSFW7

Writing a move constructor for it is tricky (@JVApen answer would work here and I like it but in a more convoluted case it would not).

Comment: So the problem now is that when you pass a moved xvalue of x to base constructor, and then   use x'member, you don't want static analyzers to emit error or warnings, right?

Comment: @KaenbyouRin - yes. Not just as "I don't want static analysis to yell",I can deal with that, It's that I don't know what would be a canonical way to write this.

Answer (score 3):

As you most likely already know, `std::move` is equal to your static_cast. Hence, technically, there is no difference.

As the underlying move constructor only knows your base class, it will be safe to access your own members. I guess the best solution here is to simply use `= default;` and ensure that all special behavior gets pushed into a separate class that doesn't have to deal with special behavior you need.

Comment: Thank you. The point of the question was "I need to write an explicit move constructor". I think static analysis might object to using move.

What would you write? A move or a static_cast?

Comment: As suggested, move the special stuff into another class (which is a member or other base) so you can use `= default`

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. That's a nice idea, I like it. What if I point inside UserType so that's not an option?

Answer (score 2):

Call `move(x)` is the most canonical way: the base move constructor would never mess up with the derive class members without invoking undefined behavior.

Note that "use after move" is usually legit, the c++ standard demands that "Unless otherwise specified, all standard library objects that have been moved from are placed in a valid but unspecified state." This means their member functions are still callable if they require no precondition. Consider this example:

```cpp
vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
vector<int> b(std::move(a));
//std::cout << a.back();  <- Invalid call. We don't know whether a is empty.
a.clear();   // Ok. clear() doesn't require preconditions.
a.push_back(0);   //Ok. Now a is { 0 }
```

Also, the validity of an object is usually required for a destructor call (which cannot be avoided if the object has automatic storage duration).